# Showing that the kernel of the homomorphism $\varphi : \Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb F_p$ is the ideal $(p,x)$ of $\Bbb Z[x]$ generated by $p$ and $x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading an example problem on the concept of generating ideals and I have some trouble with understanding the example.

They are showing that the kernel $K$ of the homomorphism $\varphi : \Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb F_p$ which sends $f(x)$ to $f(0) \pmod{p}$ is the ideal $(p,x)$ of $\Bbb Z[x]$ generated by $p$ and $x$.

The part I'm getting confused is that they note that $(p,x) \subset K$ follows from the fact that $p$ and $x$ are both in $K$, but this doesn't make sense to me. Neither of $p$ or $x$ is a polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$ so how can they even be elements of $\Bbb Z[x]$?

As far as I know $p$ is a prime number and $x$ is an arbitary variable and the set $(p,x)$ is defined as $$(p,x)=\{r_1p + r_2x \mid r_i \in \Bbb Z[x] \}.$$

What's going on here?

Edit:

Is it so that $p$ is the constant polynomial i.e $\varphi(p)=p$ and so $\varphi(p)=p \equiv0\pmod{p}$ and for $x$ I have that $\varphi(x)=0 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$? In this way it would make sense for $(p,x) \subset K$.

Comment: Indeed, $p$ is an integer and thus a constant polynomial with integer coefficients. $x$ is *the* universal variable the polynomials are in. It is a polynomial of degree $1$ with constant term $0$ and leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: But how does $\varphi$ map $x$?

Comment: $\varphi$ maps $x\mapsto 0$, because setting $f(x) = x$ tells us that $f(0) = 0$. As stated by @Thorgott, both $p$ and $x$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (former being a constant polynomial, latter being order 1). Your edit is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit (based on the comments) is correct.

To spell it out more explictly: let $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in\mathbb Z[x]$, then define

$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb F_p,\,f(x)\mapsto f(0)=a_0\mod p\,.
$$

Hence, $\varphi$ first *evaluates* $f(x)$ at the integer $0$ --which is $f(0)=a_0$ by definition-- and then considers the equivalence class of $f(0)$ in $\mathbb F_p$. This applies to arbitrary polynomials.

Take $f(x)=x$. This a polynomial of the form $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ and $a_k=0$ for $k>1$. Hence $f(0)=a_0=0$ and therefore $f(x)=x\in K$.
Take $f(x)=p$. This a polynomial of the form $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with $a_0=p$ and $a_k=0$ for $k>0$. Hence $f(0)=a_0=p$ and therefore $f(x)=x\in K$ since $p\equiv0\mod p$.